# Return Json File From APi Endpoint

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to return Json file that I get as a string from database.
I need to start a download for Json file when someone goes to this link.

This is the code I have right now.

```
public ActionResult<HttpResponseMessage> Index(string guid)
{
    var filestring = DbContext.Tasks.SingleOrDefault(t => t.GUID == guid).FinishedFiles;
    if (filestring == null)
        return StatusCode(410);

    var response = new HttpResponseMessage();

    response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
    response.Content = new StreamContent(filestring);
    response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = "result.json";
    return response;
}
```

Comment: What is your question? What doesn't work?

Comment: `public JsonResult<HttpResponseMessage> Index(string guid)` and then `return Json(FileString);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return and  download Json file from URL with this API method:

```
public IActionResult Index(string guid)
{
    var filestring = DbContext.Tasks.SingleOrDefault(t => t.GUID == guid).FinishedFiles;
    if (filestring == null)
        return StatusCode(410);

    var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(filestring);
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
    return File(fileStream: ms, contentType: "application/json", fileDownloadName: "result.json");
}
```